# Using Jmx Exporter on multiple targets

Tags: cassandra, prometheus

Is it possible to use https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter on multiple targets or i need to run multiple instance of the jmx exporter ?

I'am using run_sample_httpserver.sh script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run one instance per target, as this keeps the responsibility of scheduling and service discovery with Prometheus. It's also recommended to use the java agent.

Comment: So it is not possible to have multiple targets in the configuration of exporter?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me you can check once may if of any help, just that it needed multiple config files to be created.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69957085/use-range-of-jmx-ports-in-jmx-exporter-hostport/69970920#69970920)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).