# use range of jmx ports in jmx exporter hostport

Tags: jmx-exporter

In my VM I want to capture metrics from multiple jmx ports sometime range of jmx ports, I am using this run_sample_httpserver.sh and cofiguration YML file as

```
hostPort: 127.0.0.1:1234
rules:

pattern: ".*"
```

Here in host port i want to add multipe ports **1235, 1236 or range 1234-1250**. Is it possible to add this ? or how add multiple ports

Comment: Stackoverflow is for code part of programming, u can ask this question in https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: ok! Thanks will do it from next time!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I was not able to put multiple ports in 1 config.yml but by creating multiple config files for these ports and using below updated code I was able to use multiple jmx ports with 1 run_sample_httpserver.sh script:
[GitHub link](https://github.com/finn-no/jmx_exporter/commit/bb629c403ce647c139d88fa46ff807d65c122c6d)

[This is from issue](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues/58)